# Access getPlayerState of YouTube player on Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, firefox, google-chrome-extension, youtube

Facebook loads YouTube videos in its own iframe. When I try to inspect YouTube player properties, I see there is no available YouTube player object inside related Facebook iframe. Facebook just places a plain YouTube embed object but nothing more.

I need to access getPlayerState method of YouTube player to get the state of video. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can’t, because you can not insert any own code into facebook.com of course.

Comment: Well, I removed YouTube player and placed my own YouTube player using YouTube API. Now I can get the details by API methods.